# Shuffling decks of cards where not all cards are distinguishable

Tags: pr.probability

Suppose a deck of cards consists of $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k$ cards of $k$ types, where there are $a_i$ indistinguishable cards of each type. How many shuffles does it take, on average, to randomize the deck?  For example, $a_i=4$ and $k=13$ gives a standard deck of playing cards; $a_i=4$ for $1\le i\le9$, $i_{10}=16$, $k=10$ gives the cards for blackjack.

In general I would expect that this would be an easier task than shuffling a deck where all cards are indistinguishable.  A standard deck has about 226 bits of entropy, while the same deck without suits has only 166 bits of entropy.

---

Consider a standard deck of 52 playing cards.  Bayer & Diaconis (famously) showed that, under a certain model, it takes 7 riffle shuffles to sufficiently randomize the deck. Salem applies a different methodology and gets 6 idealized riffle shuffles. Mann uses a much stricter measurement and determines 11.7 as the expected stopping time for the riffle unshuffle (and thus the riffle shuffle) to randomize the deck.

In particular, Mann gives a formula:
$$E(\mathbf{T})=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left[1-{2^k\choose n}\frac{n!}{2^{nk}}\right]$$
which lends itself to generalization nicely.

I'm partial to Mann's method, but my question applies broadly.

---

[1] David Aldous and Persi Diaconis, "[Shuffling cards and stopping times](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/aldous86.pdf)", *The American Mathematical Monthly* **93**:5 (1986), pp. 333-348.

[2] Dave Bayer and Persi Diaconis, "Trailing the dovetail shuffle to its lair", *The Annals of Applied Probability* **2**:2 (1992), pp. 294-313. [JSTOR: 2959752](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2959752)

[3] Brad Mann, [How many times should you shuffle a deck of cards?](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/Mann.pdf)

[4] Michael P. Salem, [How many shuﬄes are necessary to randomize a standard deck of cards?](http://cosmos.phy.tufts.edu/~salem/Documents/shuffle.pdf)

Comment: The famous result about 7 riffle shuffles is actually due to Bayer and Diaconis here: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2959752

Comment: Also, depending on what you mean by "sufficiently", one might just as well say Bayer and Diaconis showed it takes 10 riffle shuffles.  See Table 1 in the paper I linked to (assuming you have access to JSTOR).

Comment: Thanks, Mark! I actually read their paper, but in my sleepy haze last night I misattributed it.  Thanks for clearing that up, I'm sure that would have confused others.

Comment: Strangely, I corrected the same misattribution on a well-known blog recently.

Comment: My mistake was misreading reference 1 for reference 2 in Mann's paper; perhaps the blog author did the same thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A place to start is the recent preprint:

[Riffle shuffles of a deck with repeated cards](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.4698)
Sami Assaf, Persi Diaconis, K. Soundararajan.

They also have another preprint about reducing this to a "rule of thumb", and cite some earlier work of Conger and Viswanath, available [here](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Edivakar/).

Pulling carelessly from tables in the different papers without checking exactly what I'm saying, it seems that in the total variation distance, (the measure which yields seven shuffles for a standard deck), four shuffles are already sufficient for blackjack, while for the separation distance (the measure yielding eleven shuffles for a standard deck), it still takes nine shuffles.

Comment: That's it, perfect!  Theorem 4.2 ff. are just what I hoped for.

I also see that this solves the other question I was considering: how many shuffles are needed to integrate U unshuffled cards into S shuffled cards: treat the shuffled cards as indistinguishable and apply the formulas from the paper.

Comment: Though in that special case you can just shuffle the U cards then integrate in a single shuffle...